# Cant update this query

Tags: php, mysqli

Hi can anyone help me on this

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("update data set anrede=?, vorname=?, nachname=?, strasse=?, plz=?, ort=?, krankenkasse=?, seit=?, personen=?, telefon=?, termin=?, time=?, vermittler=?, coment=?,feedback=?, Astatus=?, positiv=?, personen_amgaben=?, fr_1=?, fr_2=?, z_fr_2=?, fr_3=?, z_fr_3=?, fr_4=?, z_fr_4=?, fr_5=?, fr_6=? where t_id=?");
$stmt->bind_param('sssssssssssssssssssssssssssi',$anrede, $vorname, $nachname, $strasse, $plz, $ort, $krankenkasse, $seit, $personen, $telefon, $termin, $time, $vermittler, $coment, $feedback, $Astatus, $positiv, $personen_amgaben, $fr_1, $fr_2, $z_fr_2, $fr_3, $z_fr_3, $fr_4, $z_fr_4, $fr_5, $fr_6, $t_id);
```

I got this error --- `Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in`

what's wrong

Comment: Can you post the result of `var_dump($stmt);`

Comment: it gives bool(false)

Comment: What's the result of `var_dump($conn->error);`? My guess is one of the columns is misspelled or nonexistent.

Comment: string(40) "Unknown column 'positiv' in 'field list'"

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that *$stmt* is not an object. This can happen when *$conn->prepare()* fails. As from [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php):

> **mysqli_prepare()** returns a statement object or **FALSE** if an error occurred.

So, you should check whether the return value is *false*, and then check what the error is, which you can do with the mysqli [error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) method:

> Returns the last error message for the most recent MySQLi function call that can succeed or fail.

So your code could look like this:

```
stmt = $conn->prepare(" ... ");
if (stmt === false) {
     die($conn->error);
}
$stmt->bind_param( ... );
```

Note that in production mode you better not print database error messages to the browser, but in a log file.

From comments it appears that the above code prints:

> Unknown column 'positiv' in 'field list'

which is a clear indication of why the statement failed. Your table *data* apparently has no column that is called *positiv*. So correct that typo (maybe it is called *positive*?), and then try again, fixing any other errors that might be reported in this way.